# Вопрос как построить структуру формы. html/css

Tags: html, css

Есть такая форма. Буду рад если накидываете хотябы наброски, или посоветуете как правильнее её реализовать. Либо как то увеличивать размер контактного блока, либо может есть ещё более "правильные" способы?
[image: форма]

Comment: У вас-то какие трудности возникли с созданием формы? Или вы как и многие просто желаете, чтобы вашу работу кто-то сделал вместо вас? Тогда это стоит денег и вам точно не на StackOverflow.

Comment: Нет, вы очень сильно ошибаетесь. Просто думал есть более правильные способы, чем способ, который сделал я. Ответ примерно такой: h110% + transform:tr(0,-10%). Дальше давайте как-нибудь сами.

Answer (score 1):

Например так. Адаптивности нет, по этому смотрите на весь экран в сниппете.

```css
body {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.feedback {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.feedback-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.feedback__mess {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #5aadab;
  margin: 20px 0 0.5rem;
  padding: 0 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.feedback__mess-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.feedback__text {
  display: block;
  max-width: 300px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3rem 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.feedback__text-sub {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.feedback__text-title {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}
.feedback__form {
  display: block;
  width: 306px;
  height: calc(100% + 40px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: -20px 0 -20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
.feedback__input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.feedback__input:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.feedback__input-label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}
.feedback__input-input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  background-color: #f7f8fa;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea.feedback__input-input {
  overflow: hidden auto;
  resize: none;
}
.feedback__input-submit {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.feedback__input-submit input {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #f36c33;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: 0.75em 3em;
}
.feedback__checkbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
}
.feedback__checkbox input {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.feedback__checkbox label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.53rem;
  color: #777;
}
.feedback__checkbox label a {
  color: #5aadab;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="feedback">
  <div class="feedback-wrapper">
    <div class="feedback__mess">
      <div class="feedback__mess-wrapper">
        <div class="feedback__text">
          <div class="feedback__text-sub">Остались вопросы?</div>
          <div class="feedback__text-title">Расскажите нам о&nbsp;своей задаче, получите техническую помощь или&nbsp;задайте вопрос</div>
        </div>
        <div class="feedback__form">
          <div class="feedback__input">
            <label class="feedback__input-label" for="name">Имя*</label>
            <input class="feedback__input-input" id="name" type="text" name="name" required="required"/>
          </div>
          <div class="feedback__input">
            <label class="feedback__input-label" for="email">E-mail*</label>
            <input class="feedback__input-input" id="email" type="text" name="email" required="required"/>
          </div>
          <div class="feedback__input">
            <label class="feedback__input-label" for="comment">Комментарий</label>
            <textarea class="feedback__input-input" id="comment" rows="3" name="comment"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="feedback__input-submit">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback__checkbox">
      <input id="check" type="checkbox"/>
      <label for="check">Я согласен с <a href="#">политикой конфиденциальности</a> и условиями обработки <a href="#">персональных данных</a></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через гриды. Так все двигается и на маленьких экранах и можно легко сделать в колонку. Откройте пример на всю страницу, чтобы выстроилось не в одну колонку.

```css
.contact {
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 500px 250px 50px;
  grid-template-rows: 20px 1fr 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .contact {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.contact__description {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.contact__form {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 1/4;
}

.contact__agreement {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact">
  <div class="contact__description">
    <h2>Остались вопросы?</h2>
    <p>Расскажите нам о своей задаче, получите техническую помощь или задайте вопрос
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <form class="contact__form">
    Форма для заполнения
  </form>
  
  <div class="contact__agreement">
    <p>Я согласен</p>
  </div>
  
</section>
```